# android startActivity from asynctask which I execute in service

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, start-activity

I have problem of that type. I have service, in this service I execute my asyncTask, in onPostExecute method I need to startActivity. Try many solutions, doesn't help.

```
class UpdateReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, RequestResult> {

        @Override
        protected RequestResult doInBackground(String... params) {
            return performCmd(CMD_GET_STATUS, "");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(RequestResult result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyService.this, Activity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }

    UpdateReqAsyncTask updateTask = new UpdateReqAsyncTask();
    updateTask.execute();
}
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried. Put some code.

Comment: This is not enough information to determine your problem, and should not yet be reopened. What is the problem, exactly? Are you getting errors in your code? Are you getting a runtime `Exception`? Is the `Activity` just not starting? What type of `Service` is `MyService`? Where is `UpdateReqAsyncTask` defined? Is it a separate class? Or is it an inner class of your `Service`?

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for response. I solve problem! In next time try to detailed explain.